# Paginate array items in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a javascript object that needs to be displayed in paged format. For example, from the below object, I need to display this as pages based on the value of `perPage` variable.

```
{
   "fruits":[
     {
       "from":"Shanghai",
       "to":"Houston",
       "createdOn":"2019-02-20 17:02:45",
       "threadId":"1234564534"
     },
     {
       "from":"Mumbai",
       "to":"Texas",
       "createdOn":"2019-02-22 17:02:45",
       "threadId":"223455678"
     }
   ],
   "vegetables":[{
     "from":"Barcelona",
     "to":"Milan",
     "createdOn":"2019-01-20 10:02:45",
     "threadId":"45673456"
   }],
   "paper":[{
     "from":"Kualalumpur",
     "to":"Singapore",
     "createdOn":"2019-02-01 12:02:45",
     "threadId":"234222345"
   },
   {
     "from":"Singapore",
     "to":"Vancover",
     "createdOn":"2019-01-20 11:02:45",
     "threadId":"6756434343"
   }],
   "books":[{
     "from":"Jibooty",
     "to":"Ahmedabad",
     "createdOn":"2019-02-10 17:02:45",
     "threadId":"23456789"
   }],
   "toys":[{
     "from":"Shanghai",
     "to":"Houston",
     "createdOn":"2019-02-20 14:02:45",
     "threadId":"123434343"
   }],
   "electronics":[{
     "from":"Somalia",
     "to":"Angora",
     "createdOn":"2019-02-20 17:02:45",
     "threadId":"667676767"
   }]
 }
```

If the value of `perPage` is 5, this should shown as below

```
<div class="page"> 
  fruits
  vegetables
  paper
  books
  toys
</div>
<div class="page">
  electronics
</div>
```

and if the value of `perPage` is 2, there will be three div's with the class `page`. `fruits and vegetables` will be displayed in the first `div`, `paper and books` will be displayed in the second `div`, `toys and electronics` will be displayed in the third div.

I have prepared a basic code for this in vue js, but it failed in some cases. Can someone have a look at this and let me know where it went wrong ?

```
  <div class="wrapper">
<div v-for="(eachWidget, widgetName, index) in widgetData">
<div v-bind:class="((index != 0) && ((index%perPage) == 0))?'page':''" >
  <div class="widget">
    <p>{{ widgetName}}</p>
    <p class="card" v-for="(eachItem, index) in eachWidget">{{eachItem.from}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this isnt object this is json. Pagination is usually done on server because performance. You can make pagination on client but it wont improve performance. That said you can do this on several ways. You can use splice or you can make for loop that uses something like this for(let i=0;i<perPage;i++), where perPage is variable outside of loop and you change it based on hoe many perpage elements you want

Comment: with vue you can use computed properties to format data the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I calculated `pages` count based on `items` length and `perpage` number.
After that, for each page I list `items` and check `index` of `item` in `v-if`:

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        perpage: 5,
        items: {
            "fruits": [{
                "from": "Shanghai",
                "to": "Houston",
                "createdOn": "2019-02-20 17:02:45",
                "threadId": "1234564534"
            }, {
                "from": "Mumbai",
                "to": "Texas",
                "createdOn": "2019-02-22 17:02:45",
                "threadId": "223455678"
            }],
            "vegetables": [{
                "from": "Barcelona",
                "to": "Milan",
                "createdOn": "2019-01-20 10:02:45",
                "threadId": "45673456"
            }],
            "paper": [{
                "from": "Kualalumpur",
                "to": "Singapore",
                "createdOn": "2019-02-01 12:02:45",
                "threadId": "234222345"
            }, {
                "from": "Singapore",
                "to": "Vancover",
                "createdOn": "2019-01-20 11:02:45",
                "threadId": "6756434343"
            }],
            "books": [{
                "from": "Jibooty",
                "to": "Ahmedabad",
                "createdOn": "2019-02-10 17:02:45",
                "threadId": "23456789"
            }],
            "toys": [{
                "from": "Shanghai",
                "to": "Houston",
                "createdOn": "2019-02-20 14:02:45",
                "threadId": "123434343"
            }],
            "electronics": [{
                "from": "Somalia",
                "to": "Angora",
                "createdOn": "2019-02-20 17:02:45",
                "threadId": "667676767"
            }]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        length() {
            return Object.keys(this.items).length
        },
        pages() {
            return Math.ceil(this.length / this.perpage)
        }
    }
})

// just to silent vue
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools=false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label>per page:</label>
  <input type="number" v-model="perpage" min="1" :max="length">
  
  <ul v-for="n in pages">
    <li v-for="(item, title, index) in items"
    v-if="index >= perpage * (n-1)  && index < perpage * n">
      {{ title }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

hope to help